# There is a holomorphic branch of the square root of the function $f(z)=(z − 1)(z − 2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

a) Prove that for adequately large $R$ in $\Omega=\{|z|>R\}$ there is a holomorphic branch of the square root of the function $f(z)=(z − 1)(z − 2)$
b) Choose one of these branches, find the coefficient $c_{-1}$ of the expansion of the function $g$ into the Laurent series in this area, and find the integral along the positively oriented circle:

We are looking for a function $g:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ such that $g^2(z)=f(z)$. I can't think of any statements from the lecture that I could use here...

Comment: One obvious function works except on the negative real axis.  Another obvious function works except on the positive real axis.  They match except on the real axis.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(z^2(1-\frac {1}{z})(1-\frac {2}{z})\right)^\frac 12\\
z(1-z^{-1})^\frac 12(1- 2z^{-1})^\frac 12$

We have series expansions for each factor that will converge when $|z|>2$

$z(1-\frac 12 z^{-1}-\frac {1}{8}z^{-2} + \cdots)(1-z^{-1}-\frac {1}{2}z^{-2} + \cdots)$

Multiplying these together we can find the first few coefficients.
$z(1-\frac 32 z^{-1} -\frac 18 z^{-2} + \cdots)$

$c_{-1} = -\frac 18$